# Android notfication bar buttons does not working

Tags: android, notifications, android-notification-bar, notification-bar

I m developing a music player. I created a notification bar to control music after leaving app. I have three buttons(play,pause,close) on my notification.My notification was working smoothly over 2.3 OS.Notification had not worked In 2.3.6 . I added this codes into my notification class then notificaton start to working.

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 1, 
            new Intent(), 0);
```

`notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;`

But , I can not click the buttons .Because when I click it select all notification bar. How can I enable my buttons?

This is my notification class;

public class MyNotification extends Notification {

```
public static RemoteViews contentView;
private Context ctx;
public static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
public static Notification notification;
public MyNotification(Context ctx){
    super();
    this.ctx=ctx;

    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
    CharSequence tickerText = "Bando";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
    notification=builder.getNotification();
    notification.when=when;
    notification.tickerText=tickerText;
    notification.icon=R.drawable.icon;


    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 1, 
            new Intent(), 0);

    contentView=new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);

    //set the button listeners
    setListeners(contentView);

    notification.contentView = contentView;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    // used to call up this specific intent when you click on the notification

    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
    CharSequence contentTitle = "From Shortcuts";
    mNotificationManager.notify(548853, notification);
}

public void setListeners(RemoteViews view){
    //TODO screencapture listener
        //adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p storage/sdcard0/SimpleAndroidTest/test.png



    view.setTextViewText(R.id.radioname,MainActivity.rs.radioName);

    Intent radio=new Intent(ctx, HelperActivity.class);
    radio.putExtra("DO", "play");
    radio.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pRadio = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, radio, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.play, pRadio);

    //TODO screen size listener
    Intent volume=new Intent(ctx, HelperActivity.class);
    volume.putExtra("DO", "pause");
    volume.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pVolume = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 1, volume, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.pause, pVolume);

    //top listener
    Intent top=new Intent(ctx, HelperActivity.class);
    top.putExtra("DO", "close");
    top.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pTop = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 3, top, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.close, pTop);

    //app listener
    Intent app=new Intent(ctx, HelperActivity.class);
    app.putExtra("DO", "app");
    PendingIntent pApp = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 4, app, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.app, pApp);
}
```

}

And this is my Xml code of notification layout ;

```
//Xml Code of notification layout ;

  Xml layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lmain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/lmain1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >




    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/app"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nlogo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.77"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/la1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/play" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:background="@drawable/pause" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Button
        android:id="@+id/sms"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sms" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tel"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tel" /--> 

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/la2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/radioname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Deneme" 
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:background="@drawable/nclose1" />


       </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>     
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Same code is working for me. Once post ur xml code.

Comment: I updated the answer. I have added xml layout. Is your code works on Android 2.3?

Comment: I have the same problem now. Did you solve it?